# GPS enabled? always false

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Try to check if GPS is enabled on SDK 25.
Do this:

> LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)
>   view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>
> boolean isGpsEnabled =
>   manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

it always returns false. Then I start startActivityForResult as:

> view.getFragment().startActivityForResult(intent,
>   Constants.GPS_ENABLE);

this opens me settings windows, I swtich GPS on, push back button, go back to fragment and got:
1. On Activity Result responsecode 0 (always)
2. GPS enabled checking again say "false", as it is not enabled.

Moreover, I tried this:

> String provider =
>   Secure.getString(view.getContext().getContentResolver(),
>   Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
>           if(!provider.contains("gps")){}

And as google tutorial says task.locationsettings.

All tries always say GPS disabled and onActivityResult always 0.

I need both: know when GPS enabled/disaabled and recieve correct resultCode in onActivityResult(onActivityResult is called in Fragment and it is called succesfully, but with wrong responseCode in it)

What I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                Log.e("ACTIVITY RESULT", "RqC:" + requestCode + "; ReSC" + resultCode);
                if (requestCode == Constants.GPS_ENABLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    presenter.getGPS();
                } else {
                    Log.e("ON ACTIVITY RESULT", "Не дал мне прав");
                }
            }




    public void onPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.GPS_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getGPS();
                }
            default:
                requestPermissions();
        }
    }


    public void checkGpsEnabled(String caller) {
        Log.e("I AM CALLED FROM", caller);
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean isGpsEnabled = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (isGpsEnabled) {
            Log.e("CheckGPSENABLED", "Включен");
            getGPS();

        } else {
            Log.e("CheckGPSENABLED", "ВЫЫЫключен");
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Для продолжения работы приложения, пожалуйста, включите GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            view.getFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.GPS_ENABLE);
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getGPS() {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "getGPSFUSE");


        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(view.getViewActivity());


        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(view.getViewActivity(), location -> {
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.e("LOCATION", location.toString());
                        //Если получил координаты, вернуть
                    } else {
                        requestNewLocation();
                    }
                });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void requestNewLocation() {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "request new location");

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Координаты не найдены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    Log.e("NEW", location.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
    }
}

    public void requestPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(view.getViewActivity(), new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, Constants.GPS_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            checkGpsEnabled("request");

        }
    }
```

Comment: show your whole code..

Comment: @SharartiKAKA Check updates please

Comment: I think you are too much confused in getting location. Fused API has nothing to do with GPS. if gps is enabled it takes location from there. It actually selects the best provider.

Comment: Where in your code you have asked for permission at run time for location services?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA, if my GPSis turned off fused api show no coordinates and try to get new location calling requestNewLocation.

In my code I do it in onCreateView in Fragment

Comment: implement fused location api as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are too much confused in using FusedLocation API and GPS etc. Also in your question code snippet I dont see where you are acquiring runtime permission from user since your build target is 25. So you need to ask for some permissions. Like location permissions. here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) of runtime permissions

Your manifest must contain these permissions and you must acquire run time permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here the below code is for a quick over view. This snippet is taken from this [link](https://github.com/sakurabird/Android-Fused-location-provider-example). And I think this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API) is also good for you.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";
    
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;


    private final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    private final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    private final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 10;

    private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    private String mLastUpdateTime;
    private String mLatitudeLabel;
    private String mLongitudeLabel;
    private String mLastUpdateTimeLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
        mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
        mLastUpdateTimeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.last_update_time_label);
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Updating values from bundle");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
                setButtonsEnabledState();
            }

            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
            }
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        clearUI();
        if (!isPlayServicesAvailable(this)) return;
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            startLocationUpdates();
            return;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                showRationaleDialog();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates");

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                       
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                        // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mBinding.startUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mBinding.stopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mBinding.startUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mBinding.stopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private void clearUI() {
        mBinding.latitudeText.setText("");
        mBinding.longitudeText.setText("");
        mBinding.lastUpdateTimeText.setText("");
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) return;

        mBinding.latitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
        mBinding.longitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        mBinding.lastUpdateTimeText.setText(String.format("%s: %s", mLastUpdateTimeLabel,
                mLastUpdateTime));
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "stopLocationUpdates");
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    setButtonsEnabledState();
                    startLocationUpdates();
                } else {
                    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "このアプリの機能を有効にするには端末の設定画面からアプリの位置情報パーミッションを有効にして下さい。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        showRationaleDialog();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void showRationaleDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setPositiveButton("許可する", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("しない", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "位置情報パーミッションが許可されませんでした。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("このアプリは位置情報の利用を許可する必要があります。")
                .show();
    }

    public static boolean isPlayServicesAvailable(Context context) {
        // Google Play Service APKが有効かどうかチェックする
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog((Activity) context, resultCode, 2).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isPlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateUI();
        }

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(LOCATION_KEY, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY, mLastUpdateTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```